# Can I create an r script that generates an existing data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have an existing data frame that I want to use in a reprex. Is there a way to generate the R code necessary to recreate the data frame?

That is, say I’ve read in a data table from a CSV file and use dplyr::head() to get its first five rows. I want the code to create this 5-row table.

Comment: the fuction you are looking for is dput()

Comment: `dput(head(YOUR_DATA))` will create an ASCII text representation of the first six rows of your data table, with a faithful representation of the data, its format(s), and the overall data structure.